# What's the best way to include the login/logout links with CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I was thinking of putting this in the AppController, but that would mean I would have to have the same code in each view file for this. I want to put this in the header so it would be on every view. I also want there to be some logic behind it where if I am logged in then show only logged out link and my user menu. Similarly, if I am not logged in then show the register and login link. Can anyone give me a hand or point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//layout .ctp

<div class="header">
<?php
if($this->Session->read('Auth')) {
   // user is logged in, show logout..user menu etc
   echo $this->Html->link('Logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')); 
} else {
   // the user is not logged in
   echo $this->Html->link('Login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')); 
}
?>
</div>
```

is one way. If the code is in your `layout`, it will appear in every `view`, negating redundant code.

Comment: Oh I see. Layout.ctp is the way to go. What is the accompanying controller for layout.ctp?

Comment: Each view uses a layout; which you define as required. There is no controller for `layout` specifically. The default layout file is called `default.ctp`, which all views use by default. You can adjust the layout on a per-view basis by using `$this->layout = 'layout_name'` in your controller (or view, I believe).

Answer (score 1):

For Cake 3, you will need use this:

```
$this->request->session()->read('Auth')
```

Comment: **For Cakephp 3.6 and above** : `session()` depreceated use `getSession()` instead , _example_ : `$this->request->getSession()->read('Auth');`